# serial input from COM into MySql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am receiving some input from my COM port in java through this code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.comm.*;

public class SimpleRead implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener {
static CommPortIdentifier portId;
static Enumeration portList;

InputStream inputStream;
SerialPort serialPort;
Thread readThread;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
             if (portId.getName().equals("COM1")) {
        //                if (portId.getName().equals("/dev/term/a")) {
                SimpleRead reader = new SimpleRead();
            }
        }
    }
}

public SimpleRead() {
    try {
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp", 2000);
    } catch (PortInUseException e) {System.out.println(e);}
    try {
        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
try {
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
} catch (TooManyListenersException e) {System.out.println(e);}
    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    try {
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,
            SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
            SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
            SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
    } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {System.out.println(e);}
    readThread = new Thread(this);
    readThread.start();
}

public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {System.out.println(e);}
}

public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    switch(event.getEventType()) {
    case SerialPortEvent.BI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OE:
    case SerialPortEvent.FE:
    case SerialPortEvent.PE:
    case SerialPortEvent.CD:
    case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
    case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
    case SerialPortEvent.RI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
        break;
    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[20];

        try {
            while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
            }
            System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
        } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}
        break;
    }
}}
```

The input is like these:

447646

447647

447648

447649

I need to enter these values in a MySql table named 'asset '. Containing two fields ID,TIMESTAMP.
ID being the above serial inputs and Timestamp will be the time at which the input occured.

What would be the MySql query like ?

```
st.executeUpdate("INSERT into asset VALUES(What to put here??);
```

Some help would be very kindful

The Update Code:

Ok this is my Complete Code for SerialEvent:

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    switch(event.getEventType()) {
    case SerialPortEvent.BI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OE:
    case SerialPortEvent.FE:
    case SerialPortEvent.PE:
    case SerialPortEvent.CD:
    case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
    case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
    case SerialPortEvent.RI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
        break;
    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[20];

        try {
            while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
            }
            System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
        } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}

        Statement st=null;
        try{
            st=con.createStatement();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

        try{
            String Id = new String(readBuffer);
            long timet = new getTime();
            st.executeUpdate("INSERT into asset(id,timet) VALUES("+id+","+timet+"");
            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
                    }
                    break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String id = new String(readBuffer);

String query = "INSERT into asset(ID,TIMESTAMP) VALUES(?,?)";
PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(query);
pstm.setString(1, id);
pstm.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
pstm.executeUpdate();
```